# Zone ID of Unity Ads

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob

I am adding unity Ads network mediation in rewarded interstitial ad of admob. So I have both API KEY and Game ID provided by unity ad but I am confuse what to fill up in Zone ID section. 
Thanks in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

> Placements and zones are the same thing - both terms are used by the
>   industry.

Just to add to this, the `"integration ID"` is the term for Ad Placement Zone ID in the new Unity Ads Dashboard.

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/integration-id-zoneid-gameid-placement-id-im-lost.397960/